# Using CSS3 font-stretch instead of wrapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with a text that overflows when viewed from a phone. Is it possible to detect that the text is overflowing and change the font-stretch property automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not detect wrapping, and ended up using a @media rule to condense the text:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
     body {
        font-stretch: condensed;
     } }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the below meta tag in your html page?.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

If not please add it to your code, this will ensure that the page is rendering fine irrespective of from what device it is being viewed.

HTH